# Jssor Slider - How to disable automatic rotation based on EXIF?

Tags: exif, jssor

I would like to disable automatic rotation, but I cannot find any options at jQuery(document).ready(function ($) section. Please tell me where to find the option to stop it.

I have pictures with EXIF information. And sometimes I need to rotate pictures with GD Graphic library's imagerotate() command. But after saving rotated pictures, they are still shown based on original orientation. I was guessing Jssor is doing good job to find correct orientation from EXIF. But I want to stop automatic rotation so that pictures will be shown just like the way I saved.

Answer (score 0):

in sliderconfig.js or jssor.slider.js

search $autoplay variable and make it as false.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. But I found $autoplay in jssor.slide.js, and it is already set false. And I did not find sliderconfig.js file. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly find out Image Orientation using exif_read_data() php funcation after that set style='transform: rotate(X deg);' in your image tag  as per type of Orientation

---

Check the Below for sample code

```
    <div data-u="slides" style="cursor:default;position:relative;top:0px;left:240px;width:720px;height:480px;overflow:hidden;">
      <?php foreach ($pasttravelphoto as $key => $photo) {?>
                 <div data-p="150.00">
                  <?php 
                      $exif = exif_read_data(base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath']);
                   if(!empty($exif['Orientation'])) { 


                      switch($exif['Orientation']) {
                            case 8: ?>  
                                   <img data-u="image" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" style='transform: rotate(-90deg);' />
                                   <img data-u="thumb" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" style='transform: rotate(-90deg);' />
                               <?php  break;
                            case 3: ?>
                                   <img data-u="image" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" style='transform: rotate(180deg);' />
                                   <img data-u="thumb" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" style='transform: rotate(180deg);' />
                               <?php  break;
                            case 6: ?>
                                   <img data-u="image" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" style='transform: rotate(90deg);' />
                                   <img data-u="thumb" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" style='transform: rotate(90deg);' />
                                <?php  break;
                            default: ?>
                                   <img data-u="image" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" />
                                   <img data-u="thumb" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" />
                                <?php  break; 
                        }

                   }else{



                   ?>
                <img data-u="image" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" />
                <img data-u="thumb" src="<?php echo base_url2.'web/'.$photo['imagepath'];?>" />
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
      <?php }?>


    </div>
```